# parse cloud code save relation

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am developing an app with friends relations using Parse as a backend. When Alice sends a friend request to Bob she generates a notification of type 70 with herself as userA and Bob as userB. For convenience the notification also has nameA and nameB as strings.

I am trying to implement an AfterSave function on Cloud Code. This function should add Bob to Alice's "potential friends list" and Alice to Bob's "potential friends list. For some reasons I can only add Bob to Alice's list, but not the other.

Here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Notification", function(request, response) {

var namnamA = request.object.get('nameA');
var namnamB = request.object.get('nameB');
var tytype = request.object.get('type');
var alice = Parse.User.current();
if (tytype === 70) {
var bobQuery = new Parse.Query("User");
bobQuery.equalTo("username", namnamB);
bobQuery.limit(1);
bobQuery.find().then(function(bobs){
    bobs.forEach(function(bobby) {

        var bobbysRelation = bobby.relation("potFriendsList");
        var alicesRelation = alice.relation("potFriendsList");
        alicesRelation.add(bobby);
        alice.save().then(function(obj){
            console.log("alice has a new potential friend" + obj);
            bobbysRelation.add(alice);
            bobby.save().then(function(obj){
                console.log("bobby has a new potential friend" + obj);
            },
            function(obj, error){
                console.log(error);
            }); 
        },
        function(obj, error){
            console.log(error);
        });


    });
});
}
});
```

I am new to JS and I haven't been able to make this work for hours. Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned up the code a little, and added success() / error() responses, which, I believe, is why it wasn't working.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Notification", function(request, response) {

    var tytype = request.object.get('type');
    if (tytype !== 70) return response.success();

    var alice = Parse.User.current();
    var alicesRelation = alice.relation("potFriendsList");

    // EDIT - query user this way...
    var bobQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    bobQuery.equalTo("username", request.object.get('nameB'));

    bobQuery.first().then(function(bob) {
        var bobsRelation = bob.relation("potFriendsList");

        alicesRelation.add(bob);
        bobsRelation.add(alice);

        return Parse.Object.saveAll([alice, bob]);

    }).then(function() {
        console.log("success " + arguments);
        response.success(arguments);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("error " + error.message);
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

A few other notes: (0) dispense with the non- `tytype==70` cases right away, (1) `query.first()` will get just the first result so there's no need to `limit(1)` and iterate, (2) `Parse.Object.saveAll()` will save an array of objects, and that's useful since you have two.

Comment: hi @danh, thank you very much for this quick answer. Especially for the tips you gave me at the end. It definitely clears my code a lot. Unfortunately, the code provided still does not work. I am still able to record Bob in Alice's list but not the other way around. When I save [bob] only, nothing happens. When I save [bob, alice] instead of [alice, bob] nothing happens neither. Here is the error I get in Parse console:

Comment: `E2015-04-19T22:38:37.611Z] v121: after_save triggered for Notification for user YZ4yJaUGNW
  Input: { notification... }
  Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'success' of undefinedat notnotification.save.success (main.js:113:17)
    at Parse.js:3:9956
    at e (Parse.js:3:8736)
    at Parse.js:3:8185
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:661)
    at c.extend.resolve (Parse.js:3:8136)
    at e (Parse.js:3:8871)
    at Parse.js:3:8185
    at Array.forEach (native)`

Comment: @QuentinMalgaud - sorry to hear its still giving you trouble.  The log message doesn't look like it was generated by the code in my answer, for example, my code doesn't use `forEach`.  Did you forget to do a deploy?

Comment: Also, please see edit.  Just noticed that the constructor for the user query was off a little...needs to be `new Parse.Query(Parse.User)`

Comment: thank you for your attention @danh. I did use the code you provided inside another code. Now I just basically copy pasted the updated version and it still isn't working. Same situation: Bob saved in Alice's list but not the other way around. 
And still error message including  `forEach`. Even though there is nothing more than what you gave me. Code deployed. This just does not make sense. Like I could not modify and save a user after querying it.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed `error Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError` at the end of the error message. I found out something interesting over here: [link](https://parse.com/questions/getting-usercannotbealteredwithoutsessionerror)
Keep you updated

Comment: I just added `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();`
And now everything is alright. Thank you very much for your help. I wouldn't have figure it out without you.